# Propagating forward a quantum field through spacetime

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, quantum-gravity, qft-in-curved-spacetime

A fairly basic-seeming question, but one I have had some difficulty finding the answer to.

I have a (quantum) field - say a massless minimally coupled scalar field $\phi$ - on some spacelike hypersurface $\Sigma_0$ which is a Cauchy surface of some possibly-curved spacetime. I also have a second spacelike hypersurface $\Sigma_{\partial t}$ which is infinitesimally in the future of $\Sigma_0$ (that is, $\Sigma_{\partial t}$ may be found by taking all the normal observers to $\Sigma_0$, advancing each forward by an infinitesimal timestep, and then finding the surface everywhere normal to their worldlines at these infinitesimally-advanced events).

I would like to know the state of $\phi$ on $\Sigma_{\partial t}$. What is the infinitesimal generator of timelike propogation of a quantum field?

Comment: Still the Hamiltonian!